# References on building and using static libraries in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, dll

I've created a simple FTP server in C++ using Sockets, and as a part of the project I need to port over some of my code into a library. Basically I'll be wrapping some of the native Socket functions and utilizing them in library form.

The library has to be compatible with 32 and 64 bit systems, compile into either static or DLL form, and also work for debug and release mode. Our professor went over this process over the course of three hours in class, but obviously much of the process was lost on us, and it's not written down anywhere.. so I'm hoping to find a good reference on the subject that can help me do this correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [program library howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/). It explains quite well. Read also [ar(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ar.1.html)

I am not sure you should make a *static* library (eg some `libfoo.a`). *Dynamically linked* i.e. *shared* libraries (e.g. `libfoo.so`) are generally preferable. Read [Drepper's paper: *How to write shared libraries*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

Look also inside [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) source code. It should teach you a lot.

[GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) knows about [archive](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Archives) files, i.e. static `libfoo.a` libraries.